# Other than stores, what are "non-Shabbat-compatible buildings"?

Tags: shabbat, eruv-chatzerot

I was reading other answers on this site, and I wanted more information about this,

> The Greater Boston Eruv Corporation's "Halakhot of Eruv" page has a section on the limits of Eruv use including the following three main points:
>
> - **Even within an Eruv, one may not enter non-Shabbat-compatible buildings (e.g. stores) on Shabbat.**

Aside from stores, are there other buildings are not Shabbat-compatible?

Comment: Factories, I guess.

Comment: The actual text reads "Whether a community does or does not have an Eruv, one may not enter the following on Shabbat: business establishments, stores, offices, places of entertainment (movies, etc. - even if payment has been made in advance) and libraries." (see [here](https://bostoneruv.org/halachot.htm). As far as I can tell, there isn't a halakhic category of "non-Shabbat-compatible buildings", but rather this is a subjective list of places that aren't consonant with Shabbat. Even if such a category existed, it has nothing to do with an eruv.

Comment: I would accept that answer @magicker72 if you want to use an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I don't know for sure that there isn't such a category, so I won't post as an answer. The best answer would probably come from the Greater Boston Eruv Corporation itself.